# Why does 'await' fail to deliver a result with built_value in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm interested in understanding why the first expression fails to update my state, but the second one works.  This code is using built_value and bloc.

```
yield this.state.rebuild(
     (b) async => b..things = await thingRepo.things(),
);

List<Thing> _things = await thingRepo.things();
yield this.state.rebuild(
     (b) async => b..things = _things,
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Built.rebuild` is *synchronous*. If given an asynchronous callback, it will not wait for it complete.

1. `rebuild` creates a `Builder` from the original `Built` value.
2. That `Builder` is passed to your callback, expecting your callback to mutate it.
3. `rebuild` then returns a new `Built` created from the mutated `Builder`.  Note that the value returned by the callback is ignored.

If your callback did not synchronously mutate the `Builder`, `rebuild` thus will end up returning whatever the original value was.  This is what goes wrong in your first example: your callback `await`s a `Future` before mutating the `Builder`.  By the time the mutation happens, it's too late: `rebuild` already returned a `Built` value.

In your second example, you've shifted the `await` to be outside of the callback. `rebuild` gets the mutated value immediately, so that's used in the value it returns.  Note that even though your callback in the second case is declared `async`, the callback does the mutation immediately.

Consider something like:

```dart
  var x = MyBuiltValue((b) => b
    ..foo = 0
    ..bar = 0);
  x = x.rebuild((b) async {
    b.foo = 123;
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0));
    b.bar = 456;
  });
```

You'll end up with `x.foo` being `123` and `x.bar` still being `0`.

Comment: Great explanation and example, thanks.  It seems that the synchronous mutation is due to the fact that the cascade operator in the rebuild() method does not respect async - https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/23000

Comment: @Wes The synchronous mutation in the second case occurs because when you invoke an asynchronous function, that function is entered *immediately* and execution proceeds synchronously in that function until it needs to wait (i.e., until it returns a `Future`).  It's unrelated to the cascade operator.